# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when ToGet url have db parameter

Tags: java, mysql

I search the forum but nothing helps me with my problem.
I need to get database paremeter "db" by doGet mether from URL
I think this happens because program won't read my password from ULR(Yea this is bad idea to have pass into URL but this is what this Exercise needs.

Every time this happens:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This pappens when i try to launch my servet with url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Pl/?db=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/baza?user=root&password=krasnal
```

Did someone know that is the problem? Maybe something wrong is with jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/baza?user=root&password=krasnal ? I check and this is good password.

And this is my error page:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    Plain.getLargestRegionArea(Pl.java:303)
    Pl.baza(Pl.java:113)
    Pl.doGet(Pl.java:101)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.
```

I dont need to open this to open in command prompt, just need it to work in eclipse.
There are some more of my code:

```
public class Pl extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT x, y, z FROM baza";

    /**
     * Method connecting to database and gets the data needed to perform the
     * Plain algorithm
     * 
     * @param connector
     * @return The Map with coordinates in 2D space with key which is result of
     *         function z = f(x,y).
     */
    public static Map<Float, List<Point2D.Float>> dbconnection(
            final String connector) {

        Map<Float, List<Point2D.Float>> coordinates = null;

        try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          // driver not found
        }

        try {

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connector);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            coordinates = retriveData(statement.executeQuery(QUERY));

            statement.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coordinates;
    }

    /**
     * Main method. Executing and solving the problem. Should have only one
     * parameter: -connection_string .
     * 
     * @param args
     *            connection_string
     * @return 
     */

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String parametr = request.getParameter("db"); // pobranie parametru z
                                                        // adresu url

        String k="jdbc:mysql://localhost/baza?user=root&password=krasnal";
        String w=parametr;
        Locale fmtLocale = Locale.getDefault(Category.FORMAT);
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(fmtLocale);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(5);


        response.getWriter().write("Wynik to:  "+formatter.format(baza(w))+parametr);
        //response.getWriter().write(int.format(Locale.US, "Koszt : %.3f",  wynik));
    }




    public static double baza(String k){
        //String par ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/baza?user=root&password=krasnal";
      //  if (args.length == 1) {
            Map<Float, List<Point2D.Float>> coordinates = dbconnection(k);
            Plain plain = new Plain(coordinates);
            double wynik=plain.getLargestRegionArea();
           System.out.format(String.format(Locale.US, "Koszt : %.3f",  wynik));

            return wynik;
    }

    /**
     * This method gets data from {@link ResultSet} to list contains points in
     * 2D space and result of function z = f(x,y).
     * 
     * @param result
     *            The set with fetch data
     * @return The HasjMap with coordinates in 2D space with key which is result
     *         of function z = f(x,y).
     * @throws SQLException
     */


    private static Map<Float, List<Point2D.Float>> retriveData(
            final ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        Map<Float, List<Point2D.Float>> coordinates = new HashMap<Float, List<Point2D.Float>>();

        while (result.next()) {
            Point2D.Float point = new Point2D.Float(result.getFloat("x"),
                    result.getFloat("y"));

            if (coordinates.containsKey(result.getFloat("z"))) {
                coordinates.get(result.getFloat("z")).add(point);
            } else {
                List<Point2D.Float> points = new LinkedList<Point2D.Float>();
                points.add(point);
                coordinates.put(result.getFloat("z"), points);

            }
        }

        return coordinates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your password is in plaintext.. in the request URL?

Comment: my password is here: baza?user=root&password=krasnal   this is: table_name?user=***&password=****   I think that all info need to be in this url

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:8080/Pl/?db=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/baza?user=root&password=krasnal
```

The `password` parameter is being interpreted as a second parameter to the servlet, rather than part of the `db` parameter. In essence, the parameters your servlet are receiving are:

```
 db       - jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/baza?user=root
 password - krasnal
```

Sending a database password to a servlet as a URL parameter is a monumentally bad idea. **Don't do that.**

That being said, URL escaping the contents of the `db` parameter may cause it to be parsed correctly, e.g.

```
?db=jdbc%3Amysql%3A//localhost%3A3307/baza%3Fuser%3Droot%26password%3Dpleasehackme
```

I'm a little rusty on Java, so I'm not certain this will work "as is". You might need to unescape the parameter in the servlet to use this.

Comment: To expand this a bit. It is not a bad idea in general to send sensitive data to a servlet - encryption and the use of the HTTP post method provided. The problem here is that every proxy in between as well as your browser will save that password since it is part of the requested URL (details aside). Your database _root password_ in this special case. That is a Very Bad Idea™, as duskwuff correctly pointed out.

Comment: I agreed with you that giving pass to servlet as a url parameter is a bad idea, but I need this to do this exercise. String database = <db>; // where <db> is a URL parameter
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database); Could u show me how my URL should look like to maybe make this work?

Comment: @MichałWoźniczko: I'd probably use query Params for the individual parts (`user=foo&password=bar&db=baz`) and use [String.format](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/use-string-format-java-string-output) to create the actual url. Less error prone.

Comment: @MichałWoźniczko The last URL in my answer is an example of how you'd have to pass the database connection string in a URL.

Comment: @duskduff thx u helped me a lot, u have right and with your URL all works great, problem i had before was with password, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The "password: no" part sounds like it's not registering the password at all.

Otherwise, have you been able to connect to the server normally? I've had this problem before, but because there was a config error with the port access. I'd changed the port from 3306 to 3308 but there were still some config files that were still mapping to 3306. Maybe check to see if the `my.ini` file is configured correctly.

Comment: I have no problem to connect to the server, i can even give no port and it would connect me. U have right, i thing this iss password fauld fault, it didnt register it

Comment: Are you sure, you are able to connect MySQL directly from cli ? Is MySQL running? Is root is a valid user for MySQL?

Comment: cli? mysql is running, root is valid. If i change anything but no password program didnt connect to database. As a password i can write anything so i think it is password fault or some security issues maybe.